# Why does intl.Message need to be wrapped in an enclosing function?

Tags: dart

Here the a suggested pattern for using Intl.message I have seen everywhere:

```
final String learnMoreLabel = _learnMoreLabel; String get
_learnMoreLabel => Intl.message('Learn more',
    name: 'HelpContentBase__learnMoreLabel',
    desc: 'The label for a link or button which takes the user to the '
        'Google Help Center to read more information on a topic.');
```

Why can't I just write:

```
final String learnMoreLabel = Intl.message('Learn more',
    name: 'HelpContentBase__learnMoreLabel',
    desc: 'The label for a link or button which takes the user to the '
        'Google Help Center to read more information on a topic.');
```

Why does it need to be wrapped in the getter? I found this in [the docs](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/intl/0.15.1/intl/Intl/message.html):

> Use this for a message that will be translated for different locales.
>   The expected usage is that this is inside an enclosing function that
>   only returns the value of this call and provides a scope for the
>   variables that will be substituted in the message.

but it doesn't say *why*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that for that example it probably could be written that way, but it breaks down when there are parameters to the message.

What happens with Intl messages is that the a preprocessor runs over the program and finds all the occurrences of Intl.message and writes them to a file. That file gets sent for translation, and then the translations are run through another program and generate Dart code for each language, which is reachable via the messages_all.dart import.

When you call Intl.message at runtime it looks up the current locale (using the name as a key) and delegates to the appropriate translation, passing along any parameters (via the "args" argument).

When the comment says "provides a scope" it really means that the only things that are allowed to be used in the message are the variables that are provided as arguments to the enclosing function. When there aren't any arguments we could allow the enclosing function to be omitted. It would mean making the parser smart enough to recognize that pattern as well.

As an aside: I don't love the pattern of calling the method once and assigning to a final variable. It sets up a potential race condition between locale initialization and variable initialization and it means the locale can't change at runtime. However, I understand when we have frameworks like Angular that are calling it and comparing the result on every frame that it gets expensive to actually call the function every time.

Another aside: When there are no parameters you can omit the name. It will use the text as a name. When there are parameters the text is an interpolation so it can't use that as the name.